# Openshift - Blocked requests?

Tags: openshift

I've tested several http requests and only one IP is not getting any response from my server hosted in Openshit.

How can I unblock this IP?

Comment: Is what you mean is that you have tried to access your web application from multiple computers, with different IPs, and one doesn't work? OpenShift itself would block anything based on source IP address.

Comment: Exactly, how can I unblock it?

Comment: It is impossible to really know where it is being blocked. You might try and work it out by running ``traceroute`` and give the destination host as argument. This will show how far the traffic is getting. It isn't going to be anything to do with OpenShift though.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I will try traceroute but I'm still very confuse